# Awesomium change file field

Tags: c#, .net, awesomium

I am trying to make own DialogBox for choosing the file. But it doesn't work for me.

I am catching the event:

```
webView.SelectLocalFiles += OnSelectLocalFiles;

private void OnSelectLocalFiles(object sender, FileDialogEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    e.SelectedFile = "D:\\a.txt";
}
```

Where did I make mistake?

In example, Dialog Box is calling two times.

1. Pressed choose the file.
2. Chose the file from dialog box.
3. Pressed OK.
4. File didn't select.
5. New dialog box showed immediately.
6. Chose the file again.
7. Pressed OK.
8. File was chosen.

Comment: What does not work? What did you expect to happen? What example are you referring too? Do you want D:\a.txt to be preselected in your Dialog?

Comment: I found the solution, need to set Handled to Modal.

Comment: So setting e.Handled = EventHandling.Modal did solve your problem, great.You can also post your answers to your own questions here. It might help other people as well and would mark this question as solved.

Comment: Yes it is the solution of the problem. Thanks, I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set e.Handled = EventHandling.Modal.